# Angular Js : Button click to get data from two controllers and showing it in third

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I am new to AngularJS. i am having a following functionality where i am having a FirstName field and LastName Field(in two Different Controllers) and then on the click of a button i want to show FullName(First Name + Last Name) in a third Controller . Please Suggest me how to do. Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div ng-app="myApp">

       <h2>Controller 1</h2><br />
  <div ng-controller="FirstController">
   <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName">
   <br>FirstName is : {{Data.FirstName}}</strong>
  </div>
  <hr>
       <h2>Controller 2</h2><br />
  <div ng-controller="SecondController">
            <input type="text" ng-model="Data.LastName">
    <br>LastName is : {{Data.LastName}}</strong>
  </div>
      <h2>Controller 3</h2><br />
       <div ng-controller="ThirdController">
           <button ng-click="getName(Data)">Get full Name</button>
   FullName is : {{getName(Data)}}
  </div>

 </div>
 </div>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


        myApp.factory('Data', function () {
            return { FirstName: '',LastName:'' };
        });

        myApp.controller('FirstController', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.Data = Data;
        });

        myApp.controller('SecondController', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.Data = Data;
        });
        myApp.controller('ThirdController', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.Data = Data;
            $scope.getName = function (Data)
            {
                $scope.Data = Data;
            }
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not injecting your service correctly into your controllers - see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zdhwrnv/2/)

Also remove the data param from you getName() call:

```
<button ng-click="getName()">
```